# How to change system navigation bar color

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In guidelines of **Android 5.0**, the navigation bar seems customizable:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-system-bars

How can I change the navigation bar color?
I would like to use a white style.

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Edit: In my resources, I tested the style:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@android:color/white</item>
```

But the buttons are white. I would like the same renderer as the second image.

[image]

Comment: Maybe the question has evolved to a different question: How do I customize the color of the navigation bar buttons?

Answer (score 58):

Starting from API 27, it is now possible to use the light style of the navigation bar:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowLightNavigationBar):

`windowLightNavigationBar`

> If set, the navigation bar will be drawn such that it is compatible with a light navigation bar background.
>
> For this to take effect, the window must be drawing the system bar
>   backgrounds with windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds and the navigation
>   bar must not have been requested to be translucent with
>   windowTranslucentNavigation. Corresponds to setting
>   SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR on the decor view.

Comment: Unfortunately, it requires minimum API level 28

Comment: @AhamadullahSaikat It requires a minimum API level of 27

Comment: Doesn't work on Pixel 2 XL with Android 9 (API 28). I have these exact two lines in my values-v27/styles.xml, and the navigation bar changes color correctly, but it doesn't honor the second part - even though I have the android:windowLightNavigationBar property set to true, it still shows white buttons on light background.

Comment: @VratislavJindra I need a solution for this case. Do you have any solution?

Comment: @zakjma have you found any solution?

Answer (score 37):

Use this in your **Activity**.

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    }
```

Comment: what about setNavigationBarColor(Color.WHITE) ? icon color is still white.

Answer (score 19):

add this line in your `v-21/style`

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 17):

This code changes the navigation bar color according to your screen background color:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.any_color));
        }
```

You can also use the light style for the navigation bar:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR); //For setting material color into black of the navigation bar
    }
```

Use this one if your app's API level is greater than 23

```
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorWhite));
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
```

May this code will not work for API level 30. Because " SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR" is deprecated in API level 30.
Check this out: **https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR**

Answer (score 6):

the navigation bar is not supposed to be colored

> When you customize the navigation and status bars, either make them both transparent or modify only the status bar. The navigation bar should remain black in all other cases.

(source https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html )

BUT, you can use this library to achieve what you want :) https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

Comment: Thank you for your help, I edited my question with the attribute `android:navigationBarColor` but I don't want to use library.

Comment: YouTube official app changes black backrgound of navigation bar to white. Google creates a lot of rules but doesn't always implement them in own apps

Answer (score 5):

You can also set light system navigation bar in API 26 programmatically:

```
View.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
```

Where `View` coluld be `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`.

However remember that:

> For this to take effect, the window must request `FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` but not `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION`.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR).

Answer (score 3):

```
 getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.colorPrimary)); //setting bar color   
 getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR); //additional setting items to be black if using white ui
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question. But at this time we have a direct solution. May be helpful for someone.

```
public static void setNavigationBarColor(Activity activity, int color, int divColor) {
    Window window= activity.getWindow();
    window.setNavigationBarColor(color);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        window.setNavigationBarDividerColor(divColor);
    }
}
```

[View Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setNavigationBarColor(int))

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer here I finally come to this solution to make buttons light or dark.

```
    public static void setNavBarForeground(boolean light, Activity activity, View view){
    try {
        if (!light) {//make buttons dark to be more visible
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                WindowInsetsController windowInsetController = activity.getWindow().getInsetsController();
                if (windowInsetController != null)
                    windowInsetController.setSystemBarsAppearance(WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS, WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
            }
        } else { //make buttons light to be more visible
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                WindowInsetsController windowInsetController = activity.getWindow().getInsetsController();
                if (windowInsetController != null)
                    windowInsetController.setSystemBarsAppearance(0, WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                view.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Logger.log(e);
    }
}
```