# Android system navigation bar background color

Tags: android

My app's system navigation bar doesn't work as expected. Here is a screenshot showing two different Android versions's navigation bar.

[image: Left side image is API 28, Right side image is 25]

Left side image is API 28, Right side image is 25

Answer (score 0):

You can probably force a style in both (as in to prevent any changes) . If this changes, probably, there is a system parameter that is changing or doesn't exist anymore. I would take a look into styles.

I think this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47774930/2796837

Comment: What style? How would you do it?

Comment: Every component that is native follows a style, when you're a declaring your activity, if I'm not mistaken, you can fiddle around with them, I think it's Themes, but I would try to look into this direction. I'm guessing because I can't really look into your code.

I would go even further, outside of the coding box. Are this images yours and from your system or 2 different phones? Are this phones using some sort of theme?

Comment: Also this is not the bottom navigation bar, this are the in screen system buttons.

Comment: The mentioned URl doesn't help. Those attributes are already set, that's why the 1st image shows proper. However, that causes problem in lower version as shown in 2nd mage.