# Android activity system navigation bar color?

Tags: android, navbar, navigationbar

I want to create a new Activity, with black system navigationbar color, like this:
[image]

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.MyActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
</style>
```

And the result:
[image]

I also tried setting the color in the Activity with `window.navigationBarColor = getColor(R.color.colorBlack)`, but it's not working...

What sould I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using sth like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

`android:navigationBarColor` should do the trick.

Here you have a thread regarding this topic: [How to change system navigation bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348336/how-to-change-system-navigation-bar-color)

Comment: I used android:navigationBarColor before, as you can see the example... Using parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" makes it impossible to change the navigationbar color? Why?

Comment: For the Light theme there is a default value of `navigationBarColor` set to `<item name="navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>`
You can explore source code in Android Studio ;)