# How to set background in navigation bar?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to make section background part A white

and part B, which is gray in color

Make it black
No matter what I did, I could not part B change its color

I searched the sites and did not find anything
Thank you for helping me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a background for the navigation bar by customizing the theme of your app. [Ref. Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348336/how-to-change-system-navigation-bar-color)

**Option1:**

- Navigate to your app's res/values/styles.xml file
- Create a new style or modify an existing one to customize the navigation bar's background. Use the android:navigationBarColor attribute to set the background color.

  ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <!-- Other theme attributes -->

   <!-- Set the navigation bar background color -->
   <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navigation_bar_color</item>
   </style>
  ```

Apply your custom theme to your app or specific activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<!-- Other application attributes -->
</application>
```

**Option2:**

For a gradient background with two different colors for the navigation bar.

- Create a Gradient Drawable Resource:

  ```
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
       <shape>
       <gradient
           android:type="linear"
           android:startColor="#FF0000" <!-- First color -->
           android:endColor="#00FF00" <!-- Second color -->
           android:angle="90" /> <!-- Gradient angle -->
   </shape>
   </item>
   </layer-list>
  ```
- Apply Gradient Background Programmatically in Activity's onCreate method.

  ```
   // Get the window object
   val window: Window = window

   // Set the navigation bar gradient background
   window.navigationBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent) // Make navigation bar transparent
   window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS) // Enable system bar backgrounds
   window.navigationBarBackground = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_navbar_background, null)
  ```