# Match system navigation bar background with bottom navigation bar from app

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app with a BottomNavigationView. I've set the background color of the BottomNavigationView to match my app's theme, but I noticed that the background color of the system navigation bar is different from the BottomNavigationView's background color:
[My app's bottom navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oTAM.jpg)

Is there a way match the background color of the system navigation bar with the BottomNavigationView in Android? I want to ensure visual consistency across my app's UI and the system UI elements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348336/how-to-change-system-navigation-bar-color